# is it good to translate my competitor website's post?

Tags: seo, local-seo, seo-audit

my website Alxa rank into my own country is 24000 and my competitor website is 34. me and my competitor both translate the foreign post. i really don't know what kind of post should i have to translate. is it good to translate my competitor post again( i mean about a translation that is completely different(word and verb)).
does it improve my Alexa rank?

Comment: Alexa rank can be faked too. You shouldn't concern yourself to much with alexa. You should focus on writing more quality articles and hope for Good Google rankings.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, Alexa rank is more about traffic than your content. More traffic = higher rank.

From an SEO standpoint, copying another sites content is never a good idea. Even if you 'spin' the article like you mentioned by changing around certain words or re-ordering things Google will often pick up on this as 'duplicate content' and it will negatively impact your SERPS.

I would focus on increasing your website traffic if you really care about increasing Alexa rank, though I have always thought of Alexa rank as pretty meaningless. Create good, unique content and the traffic will come - worry less about copying your competitor and more about creating original content :)

Comment: thank you to answer my question. but i don't want to changing my competitor post's word or you said copy!! i just want to translate it's website post. for example my competitor website  translate a post about microsoft office word 2013 and his resource is microsoft press. can i translate a post about microsoft office word 2013 from different press for example another website like bbc.com. i don't want to do duplicate content. i don't want to copy his post. i just want to talk about his post in different point of view.

Comment: @KarimiBanam I see, I misunderstood that part of your post originally. I think you could create good, unique content by translating certain articles from English to your native language. Just keep in mind that the content should be unique, and written by you not copied from another source.

Comment: Does using my competitor keyword helpful to improve my rank? because my competitor using meta keyword tag.

Comment: @KarimiBanam According to Matt Cutts, Google doesn't even read the keyword tag - http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/keywords-meta-tag-in-web-search/ so no, using it won't improve your rank or SERPS.